# CookieManager in Android

Tags: android, cookies

The docs for CookieHandler at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieHandler.html#getDefault() says

```
Sets (or unsets) the system-wide cookie handler. Note: non-standard http protocol handlers may ignore this setting.
```

What does "system-wide" mean here? Is it like cookies of all apps will be deleted if I call `CookierHandler.setDefault(null);`

Answer (score 0):

This means all requests via `HttpURLConnection` will use `CookieHandler.getDefault()`. So if you set null all request since now will not send cookies to server.

If you want to remove cookies from current `CookieManager` you should use something like

```
    final CookieHandler cookieHandler = CookieHandler.getDefault();
    if (cookieHandler instanceof CookieManager) {
        ((CookieManager)cookieHandler).getCookieStore().removeAll();
    }
```

This javadoc not specific for android it is inherited from java se. And not means other application. 'System-wide' is only for current java process.